# Meaning of imaginary frequencies

Tags: harmonic-analysis

in a formal calculation of frequencies from a time series I sometimes get purely imaginary frequencies, i.e. $\mathfrak{Re}(\phi)=0,\ \mathfrak{Im}(\phi)\ne 0$.

**Question:**

> is there any mathematical or physical "meaning" to purely imaginary or complex-valued frequencies?

Just for clarification: I didn't encounter the imaginary frequencies as a result of Fourier analyses, but rather by "direct" calculation, so I am *not* looking for statements about possible calculation errors.

Comment: For $\omega = a + ib$, $e^{i\omega t} = e^{iat} e^{-bt}$. Are you looking for something beyond this observation?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I am looking for meaning in the sense of what role (if any) imaginary frequencies play in mathematical or physical theories; devising different representations isn't what I need.

Comment: Just to throw out some general keywords, complex frequencies in physical phenomena/models can be related to _damping_ or _resonance_ behavior. In spectral theory, _resonances_ (aka _quasi-(normal )modes_) have a technical definition and are a topic onto themselves. If that's closer to the target, a more concrete question could be formed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** *Is there any mathematical or physical "meaning" to purely imaginary or complex-valued frequencies?*

Imaginary frequencies have a meaning in physics, they are called [Matsubara frequencies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency)  The idea is that the Boltzmann weight factor $e^{-\beta H}$, with $\beta=1/kT$ inverse temperature and $H$ the Hamiltonian, can be interpreted as the quantum mechanical evolution operator $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ in imaginary time: $t\mapsto -i\hbar\beta$. Then a Fourier transform with respect to imaginary time gives you imaginary frequencies.

A more detailed analysis shows that imaginary time is compact, $0<it<i\hbar\beta$, so that the Matsubara frequencies are discrete; they can be treated as continuous in the zero-temperature ($\beta\rightarrow\infty$) limit.